# Sails:How to join two different models using waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In MVC peoples are using join query to join the two different tables, but In sails.js what I have to use? There is any method in waterline?

Answer (score 2):

The answer based on database you are using.

For instance, you need to populate values in Mongo not to join. Or you need to join tables if you are using MySQL or similar.

In a nutshell, all this stuff is covered via Waterline. So you can just declare model in `api/models` with associations. Joining and populating is executing under the Waterline adapter.

For instance, you have `User` and `Comment`.

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    comments: {
      collection: 'Comment',
      via: 'user'
    }
  }
};

// api/models/Comment.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    text: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    user: {
      model: 'User',
      via: 'comments'
    }
  }
};
```

Then you are execute `User.find()` and get already joined\populated tables from database.

But, if you want to execute manual joining, you can use `.populate()` method on Model instance. For instance:

```
// api/controllers/AnyController.js
module.exports = {
  action: function(req, res) {
    User
      .findOne('ID_HERE')
      .populate('comments')
      .then(function(result) {})
      .catch(function(error) {});
  }
};
```

You can read more about `populate` here - http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate